# PHP memory limit, Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, memory

Magento 2.3.1 / Windows 10 / WAMP64

Start Magento Admin / System Upgrade

ERROR:

"PHP Settings Check

Your current PHP memory limit is 2G.
Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more.

As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit.

(The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again"

[image]

I set memory limit 6G in the php.ini & htaccess & user.ini files.

No result.

Can help to me ?

Comment: while runing Magento 2 Commands then seen memory limit error?

Comment: Do you restart the WAMP after change the memory limit ?

Comment: which htaccess? there are multiple

Comment: 1. I runing Magento Admin -> System Upgrade. 2. I see htaccess files in magento directory  and edit this with "php_value memory_limit".   3. I restarted Apache and WAMP64 services many times. No result

Comment: Did you edit the php.ini file in the correct location ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Run:

php bin/magento cron:run

php update/cron.php

php bin/magento setup:cron:run

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your apache and server, and then check again

Comment: I restarted Apache and WAMP64 services many times. No result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set it in the wrong file. Try adding this line in the index file:

ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M')

Please let me know if this works

Comment: I've done it already in index.php on Magento. No effect: Error: "PHP Settings Check *
Your current PHP memory limit is 2G. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more. As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again."